# Can this mkdir command be simplified with further bash expansion?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, mkdir

I have a command to generate the following directory structure that I need:

```
./sites
./sites/domain_co_uk
./sites/domain_co_uk/php
./sites/domain_co_uk/cgi
./sites/domain_net
./sites/domain_net/cgi
./sites/domain_com
```

The command that creates this is :

```
mkdir -p sites/{domain_com,domain_co_uk/{cgi,php},domain_net/cgi}
```

What I'm wondering is if I can nest this with further braces so that the *domain_* and the *cgi* aren't repeated in the command?  I played around and it didn't seem possible, I did manage to change it so that both the *_co_uk* and the *_net* had both the cgi and php directories, but I don't want a php directory in _net.

When reading the bash manpage I noticed that pathname expansion takes place after brace expansion, so I wondered if I'd missed something that would allow me to simplify the command.

I'm happy the command I have does what it needs to, this is more a knowledge expansion situation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no pathname expansion in your command.

You can avoid repeating one, or the other, but not both – *unless* the 2nd expansion can be made identical for all domains expanded by the first one. Expansions enumerate all possible combinations, for example, `{a,b,c}{1,2,3}` will always expand to 3×3 strings (a1, a2, a3, b1, ...) and you can't make it exclude an unwanted value.

So if both domains had "cgi" *and* "php" subdirectories, you could use:

```
mkdir -p sites/{domain_com,domain_{co_uk,net}/{cgi,php}}
```

Note that brace expansion doesn't care what it is expanding to, and does not need to be used at boundaries only. Your original example could be rewritten to:

```
mkdir -p sites/domain_{co_uk/{php,cgi},net/cgi,com}
```

or flipping it the other way around (to avoid repeating 'cgi'):

```
mkdir -p sites/domain_{co_uk/php,{co_uk,net}/cgi,com}
```

In general though, this *does not simplify* the command (perhaps in the mathematical sense only) – it only *shortens* the command, but it actually becomes more complex to understand. Here's a better version:

```
mkdir -p sites/domain_com
mkdir -p sites/domain_co_uk/{php,cgi}
mkdir -p sites/domain_net/cgi
```